# Why this Python script doesn't properly writie an mp3 file on Windows?

Tags: python, url, file-io

I wrote this script to download songs from a playlist on my intranet music player.The script seems to work fine in Ubuntu but in windows it doesn't write mp3 file properly and there is just 2-3 sec of noise in each file and nothing else.

```
import urllib2
import json
import os
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Jukebox Playlist Downloader")
parser.add_argument("playlist_Name", help="Enter the name of the shared Playlist")

download_url = "https://channeli.in/songsmedia/download/songs/english/"
playlist_url = "https://channeli.in/jukebox/playlists_public/"
user_url = "https://channeli.in/jukebox/playlists/"

#playlist_name = raw_input('Enter playlist name: ')
args = parser.parse_args()
playlist_name = args.playlist_Name


js = urllib2.urlopen(playlist_url)
js_load = json.load(js)

id = ''
#pn = "u'"+playlist_name+"'"
#print pn
for l in js_load:
    ##print l['name']
    if(l['name']==playlist_name):
        id = l['id']

if(id==''):
     print "Sorry, playlist not found"
     ##return

playlist = urllib2.urlopen(user_url+str(id))
playlist = json.load(playlist)
songs_list = playlist['songs_list']

location = "Downloads/Jukebox/"+playlist_name+"/"
if not os.path.exists(location):
    os.makedirs(location)

for song in songs_list:
    file_name = songs_list[song]['file_name']
    url_file_name = file_name.replace(' ','%20')
    song_download = urllib2.urlopen(download_url+url_file_name)
    name = file_name.split('/')[-1]
    if not os.path.exists(location+name):
        local_file = open(location+name,'w')
        local_file.write(song_download.read())
        local_file.close()
    print "Downloaded Song: "+name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file in binary mode. Try specifying "b" in the mode argument to [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

```
local_file = open(location+name, 'wb')
```

Not the cause of your problem, but you should also use `os.path.join()` for constructing paths:

```
import os.path
location = os.path.join('Downloads', 'Jukebox', playlist_name)
.
.
.
local_file = open(os.path.join(location, name, 'wb')
```